# Java Convert an object in table format

Tags: java

I'm implementing an api that reads data from json response and writes the resulting objects to csv.

Is there a way to convert an object in java to a table format (row-column)?

E.g. assume I have these objects:

```
public class Test1 {
    private int a;
    private String b;
    private Test2 c;
    private List<String> d;
    private List<Test2> e;

    // getters-setters ...
}


public class Test2 {
    private int x;
    private String y;
    private List<String> z;

    // getters-setters ...
}
```

Lets say I have an instance with the following values

```
Test1 c1 = new Test1();
c1.setA(11);
c1.setB("12");
c1.setC(new Test2(21, "21", Arrays.asList(new String[] {"211", "212"}) ));
c1.setD(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"111", "112"}));
c1.setE(Arrays.asList(new Test2[] {
    new Test2(31, "32"),
    new Test2(41, "42")
}));
```

I would like to see something like this returned as a `List<Map<String, Object>>` or some other object:

```
    a     b     c.x     c.y      c.z     d     e.x     e.y
    ----  ----  ------  -------  ------  ----  ------  ------
    11    12    21      21       211     111   31      32
    11    12    21      21       211     111   41      42
    11    12    21      21       211     112   31      32
    11    12    21      21       211     112   41      42
    11    12    21      21       212     111   31      32
    11    12    21      21       212     111   41      42
    11    12    21      21       212     112   31      32
    11    12    21      21       212     112   41      42
```

I have already implemented something in order to achieve this result using reflections but my solution is too slow for larger objects.

I was thinking in using an in memory database so to convert the object into a database table and then select the result, something like MongoDB or ObjectDB, but I think its an overkill, and maybe slower than my approach. Also, these two do not support in memory database and I do not want to use another disk database, since I'm already using MySQL with hibernate. Usint ramdisk is not an option, since my server only has limited ram. Is there there an in memory oodbms that can do this?

I would prefeer  as a solution an algorithm, or even better, if there is already a library that can convert any object to a row-column format? something like jackson or jaxb that convert data to/from other formats.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Check this - [Jackson-Dataformat-CSV]https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after one week of banging my head against any possible thing available in my house I managed to find a solution.

I shared the code on GitHub so that if anyone ever encounters this problem again, he can avoids a couple of migranes :)

you can get the code from here:
  https://github.com/Sebb77/Denormalizer

Note: I had to use the `getType()` function and the `FieldType` enum for my specific problem.
In the future I will try to speed up the code with some caching, or something else :)

Note2: this is just a sample code that should be used only for reference. Lots of improvements can be done.

*Anyone is free to use the code, just send me a thank you email :)*

Any suggestions, improvements or bugs reports are very welcome.